# Responsive HTML email - Gmail adding classes

Tags: android, html, gmail, html-email, responsive

I am testing a very basic responsive HTML email template and Gmail (Android) is ignoring the media query.

Here's my very basic test markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
  <style type="text/css">@media screen and (max-width:580px) {
    *[class="mob-column"] {float: none!important; width: 100%!important;}
    *[class="hide"] {display:none!important;}
    *[class="100p"] {width:100%!important; height:auto!important;}
  }</style>
  <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="100p" width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" bgcolor='#ffffff'>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="center">
        <table class="100p" width="650" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <tr>
            <td class="mob-column" width="325" align="left" valign="middle">
              <img src="https://www.website.com/img/logo.png" alt="website" width="200" height="26" border="0"/></td>
            <td class="hide" width="325" valign="middle" align="right">
              <span style="font-size:12px;color:#c5c5c5;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Having trouble viewing this email? <a style="color:#666666; text-decoration:none;" href="#">click here</a></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="mob-column" align="left" valign="middle" colspan="2" height="30" style="padding-left: 15px;">
              <span style="font-size:12px; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><a style="color:#c5c5c5; text-decoration:none;" href="tel:111111111">111111111</a><span style="color: #c5c5c5;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span><a style="color:#c5c5c5; text-decoration:none;" href="tel:111111111">111111111</a></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

So class `mob-column` should stack the table cells, and `hide` should hide the table cell. Yet this is being completely ignored in Gmail on Android.

When I inspect the HTML in Gmail on desktop I can see that the classes have been altered like so:

`mob-column` is changed to `m_1371211720454434058mob-column`
`hide` is changed to `m_1371211720454434058hide`

I've followed a tutorial on Litmus (https://litmus.com/community/learning/24-how-to-code-a-responsive-email-from-scratch) and I am using https://putsmail.com for testing.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend changing your mob-column class to something like this

```
.mob-column {width: 100% !important; display: block !important}
```

We don't have to use attribute selectors anymore and Gmail and Yahoo both support standard class & id selectors these days.

Comment: I think display block is missing a will that's causing it not to break.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Gmail Android app does not support media query https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/

I highly recommend that you use inline CSS code, maybe you should try using CSS inliner by mailChimp https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

Comment: Gmail updated about a year ago to add support for embedded stylesheets and media queries. So all good now